# Get list of playlist in descending order by total videos from channel using YouTube API

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

Recently I started using YouTube API to fetch videos, playlists etc. It worked all fine but now I want to display list of playlist fetched from channel in descending order by total videos count present in the playlist. I did lot of search to find out the solution in single query, but failed to find out. I know if I want to do so, last option will be get each playlist id and query to get count and display that playlist Currently I'm using this link to fetch playlists from channel :
[Fetch Playlists from Channel](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=snippet&&channelId=%7Bchannel_id%7D&maxResults=50&order=date&key=%7Bapi_key%7D)

I thought, including max results will give only playlists which has videos more than 50, but its just to get number of playlists to fetch at a time.
Is it possible to do so or Is there any way to use just single query to get playlists from channel which has videos more than predefined count?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to achieve only by using the api ?, you could just fetch the response a keep the playlist with minimum x videos

Comment: @SofieneDJEBALI yes. Is there any other option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to filter the playlist by his number video using the youtube API,
but you could fetch the datas and keep the playlists that have $x minimum videos using PHP :

```
$response = {...} // Response from youtube API
$minimum_video = 50;
$videos = [];
foreach ($response->items as $key => $value) {
    if ($value->contentDetails->itemCount > $minimum_video) {
        $videos[] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($videos); // Should display the playlist from the object $response->items that's got minimum 50 videos
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and will let you know.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as solved if your problem is solved ! :)